# How to bind images from Properties.Resources in Xaml?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, xaml

I have some images added to `Properties.Resources`, where I can access them like:

```
Properties.Resources.LayerIcon;
```

and want to use it in Xaml, but don't know how to do this.

I know there are different ways for images to be added into a WPF project, but I need to use `Properties.Resources`, because that's the only way I found where the images show up, when the application is launched via reflection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The images in `Properties.Resources` are of type `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, but WPF uses `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource`. You can create a converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(System.Drawing.Bitmap), typeof(ImageSource))]
public class BitmapToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var bmp = value as System.Drawing.Bitmap;
        if (bmp == null)
            return null;
        return System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                    bmp.GetHbitmap(),
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    Int32Rect.Empty,
                    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Source={x:Static prop:Resources.LayerIcon}, Converter={StaticResource bitmapToImageSourceConverter}}" />
```

Make sure your Resource is set to public and not internal.

Comment: Thanks, where did you get GetHBitmap? Is it an unmanaged method I should add?

Comment: @Joan Venge, no, it's [a method of the Bitmap class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz311e4.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but I get this error for some reason: `'System.Drawing.Bitmap' does not contain a definition for 'GetHBitmap' and no extension method 'GetHBitmap' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' could be found`

Comment: Ok got it, it was a typo, there is `GetHbitmap` :O

Comment: That's really weird, now getting `Unknown build error, 'Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key Line 329 Position 40.'`

Comment: Also noticed the `BitmapToImageSourceConverter` and the usage in Xaml differs in casing. They should be identical, right?

Comment: No, it's the key of a BitmapToImageSourceConverter declared in the XAML resources. It can be anything you like...

Comment: Thanks Thomas it compiles now, but it crashed on startup. I think the problem might be `xmlns:prop="clr-namespace:ApplicationNamespace.Properties"` in this case the namespace is LayerManager. Is this correct?

Comment: Also used this `<local:BitmapToImageSourceConverter x:Key="bitmapToImageSourceConverter" />`

Comment: The error is this `LayerView.Properties.Resources.LayerIcon' StaticExtension value cannot be resolved to an enumeration, static field, or static property.`

Comment: Ah, yes, by default the resources are declared as internal... BTW, don't edit the Resources.resx.cs file manually, it will be overwritten if you change the resources. Change the Custom tool from ResxFileCodeGenerator to PublicResxFileCodeGenerator

Comment: @sky, in a C# file in your project, like any other class